# How to test if a bashrc contains a string

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Basically I want to add a string to bash_profile, but only if it does not exist so far. Would have to be something like this, but not sure how to achieve that yet

```
"{% if aem_cms_runmode == 'author' and ~/.bash_profile contains "kobold" %}
 echo 'export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
{% endif %}"
```

I did some research but couldn't find a proper way to test that in jinja. I only see to check if a variable has some value.

Comment: You can use Ansible `lineinfile` module, or `blocknifile`. Why are you trying to do this with jinja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `export PATH` in the file the task will work as you expect. But, if `export PATH` with a different value is already present the result will be duplicate `export PATH` in the file e.g.

given the file

```yaml
shell> cat bash_profile
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
```

the task below

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        dest: bash_profile
        line: "export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH"
```

will add a duplicate `export PATH` line

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ************************************************************
--- before: bash_profile (content)
+++ after: bash_profile (content)
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
+export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH
```

---

If you want to replace such a line, if it exists, you need [regexp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp). Quoting

> *"... When modifying a line the regexp should typically match both the initial state of the line as well as its state after replacement by line to ensure idempotence."*

For example, the task below

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        dest: bash_profile
        regex: "^export PATH=.*$"
        line: "export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH"
```

will replace such line, if it exists

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ********************************************************
--- before: bash_profile (content)
+++ after: bash_profile (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
+export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH
```

The task which includes `regexp` is idempotent, i.e. there will be no changes after the file was changed

```yaml
shell> cat bash_profile
export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH
```

---

If you want to add your `export PATH` only if no other `export PATH` exists test it, e.g. the `lineinfile` task will be executed only if `export PATH` is not present in the file. In this case, `regex` is not needed. Fit the pattern to your needs

```yaml
    - command: "grep '{{ pattern }}' bash_profile"
      register: result
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
      vars:
        pattern: "export PATH"
    - lineinfile:
        dest: bash_profile
        line: "export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH"
      when: result.rc|int != 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if line exists and replace only if it does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)? It does exactly that:

> This module ensures a particular line is in a file, or replace an existing line using a back-referenced regular expression. This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.

```
- name: Update PATH in ~/.bash_profile
  lineinfile:
    dest: "~/.bash_profile"
    line: "export PATH=/opt/day/libs/kobold/kobold-latest:$PATH"
```

This is idempotent.